# NetworkX: efficiently inducing clique given vertices

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Say, I have a list of vertices `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and they form a clique, is there a fast way to induce edges between them in a networkx graph? The straightforward way I can think of is:

```
from itertools import combinations

def induceClique(nxGraph, vertexList):
    for i,j in combinations(vertexList, 2):
        nxGraph.add_edge(i, j)
    return nxGraph
```

The function is alright, and you do have to add all possible pairs of edges to make sure there is the desired clique, but operating from Python it can get slow when handling long vertex lists. Maybe there is a an inbuilt function for doing this more efficiently as part of the networkx package, perhaps written in C?

Comment: (General remark) Keep in mind, that networkx is all about readability / ease of use and the pure-python nature might result in some non-optimal performance. With a very low-level library, if this operation is very important to you, you would want to access the low-level data-structures of those graphs directly to achieve maximum performance. (This is what i experienced in the past in other use-cases like mathematical-optimization and constraint-matrices; more specifically: combining numpy/scipy.sparse with python's itertools: more or less: get rid of pure python loops).

Comment: You mean sparse row format graphs are more efficient in Python?

Comment: FWIW: The networkx package is entirely written in Python, so generally if you write your own method well, it won't be much different from the networkx version (though I strongly recommend using the networkx version when it exists for usability and better confidence that it's right).  igraph has more of the background written in C.

Comment: I don't know much about the internals (and there is more than one graph-representation). But yeah. If it would be based on scipy.sparse (==c++; which it's not) you would want to exploit that fact (if performance is critical). As an addition to the above mentioned alternative: there is also [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) (less features, but some more focus on performance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate all edges, then instantiate them all at once:

```
nxGraph.add_edges_from(combinations(vertexList, 2))
```

Comment: Any reason this is faster than the above for-loop?

Comment: Because it makes one function call instead of 20 calls and does not use a Python loop.

Comment: @neo4k As you seem interested in this, maybe you should do some benchmarks for *your data*. You don't have to upvote/accept the answer before checking it out. (Although i think his reasoning could be part of the answer)

Comment: Surprisingly, the difference is marginal: my method is just 3% faster than yours (on a 1000-element clique).

Comment: For now I will accept this answer, unless something even faster comes along. This is elegant though and I like it. :)